# solving XML problem by Python

Tags: python

I have an xml file that contain a lot of information and tags.
For example I have this tag:

```
<SelectListMap SourceName="Document Type" SourceNumber="43" DestName="Document Type" DestNumber="43"/>
```

I have 40 other tags like this one with the same nodes, but the value of these nodes is different in each tag.
SourceName and DestName have the same value.

In some tags the DestName value is empty like this one:

```
<SelectListMap SourceName="Boolean Values" SourceNumber="73" DestName="" DestNumber="0" IsInternal="True"/>
```

So, I'm trying to give the empty DestName the value of Sourcename.

Here is my Python codes:

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("SPPID04A_BG3 - Copy - Copy.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for SelectListMap in root.iter('SelectListMap'):
    #DestName.text = str(DestName)
    for node in tree.iter('SelectListMap'):
        SourceName = node.attrib.get('SourceName')
    SelectListMap.set('DestName', SourceName)  
tree.write("SPPID04A_BG3 - Copy - Copy.xml")
```

This program is not working on the right way. any help or ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please show the erroneous output or any other errors it is producing given an input?

Comment: When I run it I don't have error. But the DestName value in all tags change to a wrong value. My idea is give the empty DestName the same value of SourceName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never check the if the `DestName` attribute is empty. If you replace the first for loop with the following, you should get what you want:

```
for SelectListMap in root.iter('SelectListMap'):
    if SelectListMap.get("DestName") == "":
        SourceName = SelectListMap.get("SourceName")
        SelectListMap.set("DestName", SourceName)
```

Comment: Now when I run it the empty DestName will have the right value. But the order of the tag changed. The tag will be like this:       <SelectListMap DestName="Document Type" DestNumber="43" SourceName="Document Type" SourceNumber="43" />    So, how can I give the DestName the value but without changing the order of nodes inside the tag.

Comment: As far as I understand, Etree always outputs attributes in alphabetic order. See https://bugs.python.org/issue34160 where preserving the order is discussed.